# Examples in Mathematica official site can't run in Mathematica 13.0

Tags: example

I see this example in the [website](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html.en)

```
Solve[a x + y == 7 && b x - y == 1, {x, y}]
```

But in my computer, the result is
[image]
The code is:

```
Solve[a x + y == 7 && b x - y == 1, {x, y}]
```

What's wrong with the example?

Comment: I get a result with MMA version 13.0. Have you tried with a fresh kernel?

Comment: @DanielHuber May you tell me how to fresh kernel.

Comment: `b` is "black" which means it must have been previously assigned a value.  Starting with a fresh kernel or executing `b = .` should make things work.

Comment: @JimB Thanks. How to start with a fresh kernel?

Comment: `Quit[]` will kill the kernel and allow you to start "fresh". However, `Clear[<your variable names>]` or `Clear["Global\`*"]` is usually sufficient to resolve many problems. For the equations in your comment, you have four unknowns but only three equations. The solution will be for three of the variables in terms of the fourth variable.

Comment: `Evaluation->Quit Kernel->Local` and execute code to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9JOK.png).

Comment: Please keep your original question! Do not edit it since there is an answer!

Answer (score 1):

use `Assumptions`

```
Solve[{a x + y == 7 && b x - y == 1}, {x, y}, Assumptions -> a + b != 0]
```

[image]